# How was the gift of the word of knowledge defined by the pioneers of the pentecostal healing revival?

Tags: pneumatology, spiritual-gifts, pentecostalism, knowledge

I will ask a series of questions concerning individual spiritual gifts (pneumatika/charismata), or manifestations of the Spirit in 1 Cor 12.

This second one is also about **the gift of the word (logos) of knowledge (gnosis)** (1 Cor 12:8), and it is closely related to [the first one](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/14069/1407).

How did **the pioneers of the [healing revival](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Healing_Revival)** (Branham/Coe/Roberts/etc) speak about this specific gift, e.g in the Magazine *The Voice of Healing* or in their sermons or testimonies?

Comment: Just to make clear. The other question is about the first generation of pentecostal pioneers (1900-1940), this question is about the healing revivalists of the 50's. Thus the questions are not identical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**W. V. Grant** wrote in THE VOICE OF HEALING October 1953 Page 24 about the word of knowledge.

> WHAT IT IS
>
> The Spiritual gift of the word of knowledge is certain
>   facts in the mind of God, which He sees fit to reveal to a servant
>   supernaturally by His Spirit. It is only a “word,” or a portion of
>   God's great storehouse of knowledge. God speaks in divers manners,
>   such as dreams, visions, revelation, or in audible voice. It is always
>   conveyed supernaturally as any other gift. This gift can tell the
>   whereabouts, conditions, nature, or thoughts of a person, animal,
>   place, or thing even when it is impossible to learn it in the natural.
>
> It is different from the Spiritual gift of faith in that it lets you
>   know things even when you did not pray for them. The Spiritual gift of
>   faith deals with things “not yet come to pass,” else it would not be
>   faith. It is not a vocal gift, as it makes you to know and not to
>   speak. It is not discerning of spirits, as it has nothing to do with a
>   supernatural spirit. It helps one, to look into the heart, mind, or
>   nature of a man and to know his secrets and intentions. It has helped
>   people find lost articles, but its main purpose is to find lost souls.
>
> BIBLE EXAMPLES
>
> While Peter was lying flat on his back on the house
>   top, the Spirit of God told him three men were seeking him (Acts
>   10:19). Had Peter gone to school one hundred years he could not have
>   gained such knowledge, The all-knowing God gave part of His knowledge
>   to Peter by the Spirit.
>
> The Spirit of God told Samuel that Saul's
>   asses had already been found, and let him know all that was in Saul's
>   heart (1 Sam. 9.19-20). A voice from God told Elijah that God had
>   seven thousand who had not bowed their knees to Baal (1 Kings 19:18).
>   A spiritual revelation!

And before that he wrote, in direct contrast to pentecostal pioneer Donald Gee:

> This gift has no mixture with the natural.

Now I only need to know if this view was shared by the other leaders during the same era.

Comment: By the way, that is not the W V Grant who has been involved in financial scandals and been exposed by James Randi, but his father.

Comment: http://vimeo.com/25341979 Is this the sort of thing you're looking for? Its a video of Branham where he claims to know about people's sickness and their state. This fits with what Grant said was the definition of "the gift of the word of knowledge". I would write an answer but I haven't found anything specific written about it by these men but I'll keep looking.

Comment: Please do. I might add that what I am currently doing is inquiring about the theology side of the gifts. Thus I need texts or other sources when the gift is explained, rather than demonstrated. (unless that demonstration is combined with an explanation.)

Comment: The people you mention are not mainstream Pentecostals. But the idea of the gift of knowledge is more or less people seeming to know details about people lives.  For example a person might pray and say 'I am seeing a person in their garage with a lot of newspapers around a car and God is saying to you...' or 'Somebody in this room has just visited a doctor and God wants you to come forward for prayer...On the more extreme end like Branham hypnosis is partly related to the movement. http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/9664/how-do-reformed-theologians-view-hypnosis/9686#9686

Comment: I am deleting my answer and upvoting yours. I have been reading about Branham and underestimated his influence on later pentecostal movements. Cheers.

Comment: OK. I am still investigating the issue and will perhaps provide a more thorough answer in time.

Comment: I have now read through every relevant passage in the Magazine 'The Voice of Healing', the leading publication of the healing revival, plus some relevant books. I think the opinion of Grant is mainstream in the movement, and will set my answer as the accepted one.